# select first element from search bar with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im trying to select the first element of from the list of suggestions after sending a key in the search bar. Here the code im using at the moment:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://slotcatalog.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"cookie-ok"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"subs-close"))).click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selsearch")
elem.send_keys("Starburst")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).click()
```

but the error says "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'" - do you know how i can fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would be useful if you added the whole call stack generated by the error so we can see which line produced it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need `selenium` at all:

that's can done easily via:

```
import requests

params = {
    "blck": "topSrch",
    "lang": "en",
    "search_input": "Starburst"
}


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
}

goals = ["name", "url"]


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url, params=params).json()
        goal = [[item[g] for g in goals] for item in r]
        print(goal[0])


main("https://slotcatalog.com/json.php")
```

Output:

```
['Starburst', '/en/slots/Starburst']
```

Now you can make your request to the url easily.

Or if you want to use `selenium` so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://slotcatalog.com")
    goal = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "#selsearch").send_keys("Starburst")
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.tt-suggestion:nth-child(1)"))
    )
    element.click()


main("https://slotcatalog.com")
```

Comment: great thank for the help! I didnt know that i had to use "nth-child(1)", cheers!